# Working with a very large existing database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to design a DAL for an existing application that works with a very large database (has around 800 tables, another 500 stored procedures, lots of views and user functions). I also want to enable the use of migrations for changes moving forward.

This is what I came up with:

1. Use EF Power Tools to reverse engineer the tables into EF entities in a temporary project
2. Enable migrations in that project.
3. Add the first migration, which scaffolds the creation of every table (unfortunately, leaving out default values for columns)
4. Separate entities into separate models (each model would have its own project and its own context class)
5. Enable migrations on only one of the models. Do all changes there.
6. Add a migration and copy the content of the migration that was scaffolded earlier.

Does this sound like a good plan? What would you change?

This would only help create the tables, though. If I want the whole database to be created with that initial migration, how could I add the creation of stored procs, views and user functions to this initial migration?

Because of this, I'm thinking that the best option would instead be to have a backup of the initial database, restore it whenever I want a new database setup, then run migrations to upgrade to current version.

What is the general approach to solve this problem?

Comment: This question verges on being "opinion-based" which isnt a good fit for SO's Q&A format. You may want to consider rephrasing the question to be more concrete and objective. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Updated, Jeff. I'm looking for the solution other developers have used for this problem.

Comment: The answer is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx).